# All possible variants of a string with capital and lowercase letters

Tags: ruby

This was asked me in a coding quesiton, and I gave kind of an ugly, though working solution. Would love to see a master's beautiful solution to this question.

Given a string that includes letters and numbers i.e. `"abCd1_k"`, return an array of every variant string with the capitalization of the letters changed, i.e., `"AbCd1_k"`, `"ABcd1_k"`....

A more simple problem case then 'AbCd1_k' would be 'ab', which should return ->

['ab', 'Ab', 'aB' 'AB']

It seems to me that even the most beautiful solution will still have an expensive time complexity by definition. (at worst, you could 2 combinations for each character, which would mean 2^n growth). Even if this is true, there must be a really beautiful way to do this in Ruby.

Comment: The question is not clear. 1. In the title, you ask for permutations but in the question, you ask for combinations. Which? 2. You wrote "capitalization of the letters changed", but in `""AbCd1_k"", some letters case are retained. Which?

Comment: ohp, apologies guys, I think I was confusing my terminology. I updated the question to be a bit more clear, suggestions are welcome too :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
def case_permutations(string)
  string
    .each_char
    .reduce(['']) do |acc, char_string|
      acc.flat_map do |prefix|
        [char_string.upcase, char_string.downcase]
          .uniq
          .map do |modified_char|
            "#{prefix}#{modified_char}"
          end
    end
  end
end
```

You're not going to do better than (2^n)*n time complexity because your return value will have 2^n items of length n in the worst case.

Comment: Nice solution.  You could replace `.split('')` with `.chars` or (maybe better, the enumerator) `.each_char`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def case_combos(str)
    c = str.split('').map { |x| [x.upcase, x.downcase]}
    (0...1<<str.size).to_a.map do |x|
        z = ""
        0.upto(c.size-1) do |y|
            z += c[y][0] if (1<<y)&x == 0
            z += c[y][1] if (1<<y)&x != 0
        end
        z
    end.uniq
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def every_combination(str = '')
  return unless str
  str.chars.permutation(str.size).map do |perm|
    perm_char_case_pair = perm.map do |c|
      [c.downcase, c.upcase]
    end
    perm_char_case_pair[0].product(*perm_char_case_pair[1..-1]).map(&:join)
  end.flatten.uniq
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```rb
class String
  def case_combinations
    downcased = self.downcase
    [0, 1].repeated_permutation(self.size).to_a.map do |binary_casing|
      permutation = downcased.dup
      binary_casing.each_with_index.map do |binary_case, index|
        permutation[index] = permutation[index].upcase if binary_case == 1
      end
      permutation
    end
  end
end
```

Basically it creates all possible combinations of 0 and 1 given a length of string, taking that it takes the 1s as representing upcase.

```rb
'abc'.case_combinations # ["abc", "abC", "aBc", "aBC", "Abc", "AbC", "ABc", "ABC"]
```

If some characters are not letters, it would return duplicates but adding `uniq` would fix it.