# Can inflect.acronym statements in rails be dynamic. i.e. based on a table, not hardwired in the code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a situation where I am titleizing categories. I need to have acronyms such as HR and ISO in all caps .

I am currently doing that in the inflections initializer with

```
 ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
   inflect.acronym 'HR'
   inflect.acronym 'ISO'
 end
```

However, as I understand it, the exceptions need to be hardwired into the code. Is there any way to have the initializer read a table? That way, the user could add the acronym exceptions on the fly.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298620/all-possible-variants-of-a-string-with-capital-and-lowercase-letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the initializer is still only going to run on application restart, so adding records to a table "on the fly" won't automatically add to your inflections.

but you could try...

```
class MyInflection < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :add_inflection

  def add_inflection
    ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) {|i| i.acronym my_acronym }
  end
end
```

This assumes you have a model MyInflection, table "my_inflections" with an attribute "my_acronym"

To load the existing inflections on restart, set the initializer as...

```
 ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  if defined?(MyInflection)
    MyInflection.all.each { |i| inflect.acronym i.my_acronym }
  end
 end
```

the test for `defined?` is to prevent errors when the table hasn't been defined (new database, or not yet migrated)

Comment: Steve - Thanks for the reply. Given the scope of this project and the amount of new acronyms that would probably be added, I'll probably stick with a manual approach, especially since the server has to be restarted for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

If I have a plain old Ruby object like this:

```
  class MyInflector
    class << self
      def new_inflection(i)
        ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
          inflect.acronym i
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

And I fire up IRB, then I can do this:

```
  irb(main):001:0> class MyInflector
  irb(main):002:1>   class << self
  irb(main):003:2>     def new_inflection(i)
  irb(main):004:3>       ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  irb(main):005:4*         inflect.acronym i
  irb(main):006:4>       end
  irb(main):007:3>     end
  irb(main):008:2>   end
  irb(main):009:1> end
  => :new_inflection

  irb(main):010:0> "hr".titleize
  => "Hr"

  irb(main):011:0> MyInflector.new_inflection("HR")
  => /HR/

  irb(main):012:0> "hr".titleize
  => "HR"
```

With this, you can create a view to let the user define new inflections. I imagine in the controller associated with said view, you would take care of both persistence and loading of the new inflection, as above.

On later restarts, persisted inflections could be loaded as per SteveTurczyn. But, I believe this allows you to define inflections without requiring a restart.

I think this is what you had in mind?

UPDATE:

In reading SteveTurczyn's post more carefully, I didn't do anything different than he did. He organized it differently and my eye missed the ActiveSupport::Inflector call. So, please accept his answer if either of these meet your needs. Apologies to Steve.

One other very small and purely-stylistic difference (which is, perhaps, obvious). Recently, I have been trying to keep all non-persistence logic out of my AR models. Which is why I went with the PORO approach. I've also been trying to keep my controllers super skinny. So, in truth, I would likely have had another PORO that sits between the controller, MyInflector, and Steve's MyInflection. That all might be too much overhead for your situation, but I found your question interesting so thought I would tack this on.

Comment: As I replied to Steve, I'll probably stay with manual changes given the scope of the project and the need to restart the server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Chris - sounds good! Hey, just to be clear and FWIW, a server restart is **not** needed (which is what I demonstrate in the IRB session at the top of my answer). When I first read Steve's answer, I thought he was saying a restart is required in all circumstances. But, that's not what he's saying. It's the "But you could try..." bit where he shows how to do it without a server restart. Anyway, good luck!